# DataGrid: Have a stable/fixed row for a "group" of items

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I need to create a DataGrid that shows a list of customers including their income. I have two DataTables (customer/income) that I merge into one query and the result is a list of customer/income items.

I now want to display all customers including their incomes in one table, but without duplicating/showing each customer for each income row. So I want to hide all other drawing of the customer when it has been drawn once.

The customer row should always be on top. Sorting should be possible. In other words I'm looking for a grouping feature without having a group.

[image: Regular display when opening for the first time]

It should not happen for the columns of the customer that it looks like this:

[image]

Another option could be a grouping, but then I want to have the same "column" like display with resizing behavior also in the grouping element.

Any thoughts would be highly welcome.

Comment: Please post your XAML code as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could replace the CellTemplate of the Income Column with a Template holding a DataGrid on its own.

[image: pic unsorted]

[image: pic sorted]

XAML

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer" Binding="{Binding Customer}" >
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Birth Date" Binding="{Binding Date}" >
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Income" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding IncomeList}" 
                                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                  HeadersVisibility="None"
                                  CanUserAddRows="False" 
                                  CanUserDeleteRows="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn
                                      Width="*"
                                      IsReadOnly="True" 
                                      Binding="{Binding Path=.}">
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have also tried this, having a grid-in-a-grid solution. The problem is that the DataGrid behaves absolutely weird. There are several posts around this. One problem is that the mousehweel does not work correctly anymore, another is, that the scroll does not update correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DatagridRowTemplate` for this purpose.

You will have two columns in your `DataGrid` and in your `DataGridRowTemplate`, You have a `ListBox` showing all Incomes of a single Customer.

Your XAML code will be something like this.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding CustomerName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Birthday" Binding="{Binding CustomerDOB}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Incomes}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Assuming you have a `List/ObservableCollection` named `Customers`. And `CustomerName`, `CustomerDOB` and `Incomes`(A list of Customer Incomes) are your property names for customer class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this, but I want to have the incomes not in the details, but in the main grid. Indeed the information of the income is much larger than displayed here. There are some 20 items for the customer. And, in the RowDetails I do not have the possibility to resize columns, and furthermore I need the rowdetails for some other information.